# Making a XMLHttpRequest to a local JSON file to console log data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, express, xmlhttprequest

*full disclosure: total noob*

I have a file, "data.js", it contains data, that looks like this:

```
[{
   "Course": "Math 101",
   "Classroom": "Granby Hall"
 }]
```

I have a server file, currently hosting my app using express, looks like this:

```
app.get('/data.js',function(req,res) {
    res.send('data.js');
 });
```

In my main js page, where I'm making my request, it looks like this:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open('GET','data.js', true);
x.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(x.readyState == 4){
    console.log(x.responseText);
    callback(JSON.parse(x.responseText));
}
};
x.send();

function callback(resp){
console.log(resp);
}
```

When I open the devtools and inspect, the console does log ' data.js ' (not in string quotes), and then the next line is an error:
"uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0"

I tested it, changing the file name that's sent in my response from the server, and that's what it's talking about.  So, really I'm just confused. What's happening? I want to see the data from my data.js file in the console as an object.  But it looks like it's literally just trying to send the file name, and then it fails to parse it, because it's literally sending the file name.

Answer (score 0):

For me your code works exactly as you seem to want it to. Are you receiving an error message in the console?

I did have the data.js in the wrong folder and had to change my path (lol), but other than that it outputs your json to the console when I run it.

Comment: Yes, I've got two console errors:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)    http://localhost:3000/data.json

and "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0"  localhost/:1

Comment: is localhost:3000/data.json the location of your file? (you have it listed as data.js in your example) it should not respond with 404 if the file is where you are pointing.

Comment: Ok, I fixed my 404 problem, I had it as data.json instead of data.js, but now I've got an error that says:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0    localhots/:1

no clue, whats going on, earlier it said unexpected token C, now it's D?!?

Comment: is the data file exactly as described in your question? Usually this error comes from malformed JSON strings, it is fine as given in your example. You could try console.log on the string before parsing to see what it is that you are trying to parse.

Comment: It's not the exact same, I used sample data in my example. I will try to get it formatted better.  I actually used a CSV to JSON converter for the data, so maybe that's the problem. I'll try that.